# MongoDB, is this deeply nested data model good?

Tags: mongodb, schema

I am new to MongoDB. I have two collections, `Stories` and `Users`. Stories consists of only two keys, a headline and a url, besides the object_id. For the `Users` collection, I have the following schema in mind, shown here as a python dictionary/json.

```
users = {
    "username": {
        "stories_liked": [], # array of story object_id's
        "stories_disliked": [], # array of story object_id's
        "bag_of_words": {
            "word1": {"pos": 0,"neg":0},
            "word2": {"pos": 0,"neg":0},
            # hundreds of thousands of words...
         }
    }
}
```

I realize though that there is *a lot* of duplication here. I designed it this way for atomicity and fast lookups. I want to know if something different would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is a duplication here? The ok-ness of your schema depends on how would you use it. The data is pretty much useless if you do not provide you are you going to modify/consume it.

So if you just store your data and then only retrieves it, your schema may be good. On the other hand if you are going to modify your element many ways (add/remove stories the user likes/dislikes, modify bag of words) your schema becomes pretty bad. The same goes if you will have some (or even worse many) super active users which will start liking/disliking almost everything.

Not really relevant, but if you speak about mongo, there is no point to write python dictionary - you can just post a json.

Comment: The duplication is where each user has his own bag of words, which is a dictionary containing thousands of words. 
I designed it this way because I need really fast lookups - what is the pos count of this word for that user -, and atomicity - if a new story is added to stories_liked then the words of the story must be added to the bag of wards in the same transaction. This is for a classifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the model is OK.

First, it is not deeply nested. Only 4 layers

Second, it seems that u have many-to-many relations among stories and users, words and users.  Moreover, u need fast look-up and atomicity on "word". Using this structure seems well justified.

U can maybe use the following structure as an alternative:

```
"username": {
    "stories_liked": [], # array of story object_id's
    "stories_disliked": [], # array of story object_id's
    "POS":{word1 : 3, word2 : 4, ...} # hundreds of thousands of words...
    "NEG":{word1 : 5, word2 : 6, ...} # hundreds of thousands of words...
}
```

This changes performance of certain queries and index. To be tested. Anyway, u should use embedded model if u need atomicity on insert and update, and that's what u are doing now.